# Could not create a category-wise subcategories dropdown list using the components

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a category-wise subcategories dropdown list in the menu bar dynamically.but I don't understand how I will create proper relations with each other(category and SubCategory) for dropdown. I can create dynamically menu bar using my "Category" list which is contain my database.but I don't understand how I create a category-wise subcategory menu bar as a  dropdown list.

Here is my code:

_Layout.cshtml

```
//other code
 
                            @(await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryWiseMenu"))
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>


//other code
```

CategoryWiseMenu.cs

```cs
public class CategoryWiseMenu:ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public CategoryWiseMenu(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var c = _db.Category.OrderBy(p => p.CategoryName).Include(p=>p.SubCategories);
        return View(c);
    }
}
```

~/Views/Shared/Components/CategoryWiseMenu/Default.cshtml

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">

    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
    <li class="nav-item text-dark">
        
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a asp-controller="ShopShow" asp-area="Customer" class="text-dark mt-2">@category.CategoryName</a>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split mt-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </a>

            @for (int i = 0; i < category.CategoryName.Length; i++)
            {
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@category.SubCategories.SubCategoryName[i]</a>
            </div>
            }
            
        </div>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Here is this relation between Category and SubCategory:

[image]

Category and Subcategory Model:

```
//Category.cs

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

//SubCategory.cs

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "SubCategory Name")]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

When I Run my application,i found an error:
[image]

Actually, I don't understand, my implementation is ok for the category-wise subcategory dropdown list or not.how I solve this issue. I am an absolute beginner, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below codes:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < category.SubCategories.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@category.SubCategories.ToList()[i].SubCategoryName</a>
    </div>
}
```

**Update:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    @for (int i = 0; i < category.SubCategories.Count; i++)
    {
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@category.SubCategories.ToList()[i].SubCategoryName</a>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: @mj1133 Not Working. I have found this error: 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<GhatiaBazar.Models.SubCategory>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Comment: @Linkon Can you show us the whole code of Default.cshtml.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVsHSUqwvf2opxq5TMXisHUAIS-9PCBj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: too long character, for that I upload this google drive .please check. I am using asp.net core MVC 2.2

Comment: @Linkon, seems you didn't add model to the page. Add this line at the top of this page: `@model IEnumerable<Category>`

Comment: Now I found an unexpected output.When I click "men", I found just one subcategory of this dropdown list in the menu. same as "women".but I want to found all subcategories in my categories as a dropdown list. my database has 2 categories has 2 different subcategories. I want to show all subcategories as a dropdown list's categories.

Comment: @Linkon You should put the for loop in the `<div class="dropdown-menu">`, see my update.